# Writing a python Dictionary to a CSV file with keys as column headers

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I'm trying to write the elements in my dictionary into a text file where each key would be a column. Currently have I something that looks like

```
import csv
import numpy as np



data1 = np.arange(10)
data2 = np.arange(10)*2
data3 = np.arange(10)*3

writefile = '../Desktop/data.txt'
datadict = {} 

datadict['data1'] = data1
datadict['data2'] = data2
datadict['data3'] = data3


f = open( writefile, 'w' )
fieldnames = ['data1','data2', 'data3']
data = csv.DictWriter(writefile, fieldnames, restval='', extrasaction='ignore', dialect='excel')

f.close()
```

but it gives me the error "argument 1 must have a "write" method". I'm not sure what that means. I'm also worried about the dialect = 'excel', but I'm not sure what else to put. 
In the end I'd like a file that has something looking like:

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No need to use DictWriter here at all:

```
import csv
import numpy as np

data1 = np.arange(10)
data2 = np.arange(10)*2
data3 = np.arange(10)*3

writefile = '../test.csv'
fieldnames = ['data1','data2', 'data3']
with open( writefile, 'w' ) as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(fieldnames)
    writer.writerows(zip(data1, data2, data3))
```

Answer (score 2):

You should pass the file-like object as the first argument to the `DictWriter` constructor.

```
datalist = [{'data1': d1, 'data2': d2, 'data3': d3} for d1, d2, d3 in zip(data1, data2, data3)]
...
f = open(writefile, 'w')
...
writer = csv.DictWriter(f, ...) 
for i in xrange(10):
    writer.writerow(datalist[i])
f.close()
```

More simple analogic case:

```
with open(writefile, 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for row in zip(data1, data2, data3):
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: This gives me an error since the file doesn't already exist. When I put an empty file there it returns the empty file.

Comment: fixed, try again) (I forgot `'w'` modificatory, and you should close the file or flush it)

Comment: I did and still I end up with an empty file

Comment: we forgot to use `writer.writerow` (http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv.writer). This should work.

Comment: I'll try that for loop after diner, but that looks promising. thanks.

Comment: The with statement is wrong, it should be `with open(writefile, 'w') as f:`

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing the kind of data analysis it looks like you might be doing here, the best bet might be to get into [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/), Python's dedicated data analysis library.

Here's an example which does what you want:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data1 = np.arange(10)
data2 = np.arange(10)*2
data3 = np.arange(10)*3

df = pd.DataFrame(zip(data1, data2, data3), columns=['data1', 'data2', 'data3'])
df.to_csv('myfile.csv')
```

Pretty neat I'd say. Additionally, you can now do [all](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort.html) [sorts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25748683/python-pandas-sum-dataframe-rows-for-given-columns) of [unimaginable](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html) [things](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26537878/pandas-sum-across-columns-and-divide-each-cell-from-that-value) with your data.

You can also make a `DataFrame` from an existing dictionary:

```
In [115]: a_dict = {'foo':[1,2,3], 'bar':[4,5,6], 'baz':[7,8,9]}

In [116]: pd.DataFrame(a_dict)
Out[116]: 
   bar  baz  foo
0    4    7    1
1    5    8    2
2    6    9    3
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import csv
import numpy as np

data1 = np.arange(10)
data2 = np.arange(10)*2
data3 = np.arange(10)*3

writefile = '../Desktop/data.txt'
datadictlist = [{'data1': data1[i], 'data2': data2[i], 'data3': data3[i]} for i in xrange(10)]

f = open( writefile, 'w' )
fieldnames = ['data1','data2', 'data3']
writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames, restval='', extrasaction='ignore', dialect='excel')
writer.writerows(datadictlist)

f.close()
```

Comment: That just gives me an empty file without any data written in it.

Comment: It's now printing data (yea), but not in the right format. It's giving me one line with [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9],[ 0  2  4  6  8 10 12 14 16 18],[ 0  3  6  9 12 15 18 21 24 27]

Comment: @AlexaHalford, that is because you are assigning the whole array to a single field in one dictionary. I updated the code to print the output you want to show.

Answer (score 0):

put 'a+' instead of 'w'

```
f = open( writefile, 'a+' )
```