# Sum only negative numbers across columns in dataframe Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to sum by only negative numbers across all the columns in a dataframe.

I have seen this post: [Pandas: sum up multiple columns into one column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42063716/pandas-sum-up-multiple-columns-into-one-column)

My data looks like this:

But I would like to sum only the negative numbers. How do i do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `mask`

```
df.iloc[:,1:].where(df.iloc[:,1:]<0).sum(axis=1)
```

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest you avoid `apply`; it can be slow.

This will work: `df[df < 0].sum()`

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to use `abs`:

```
df['neg_sum'] = df.where(df != df.abs()).sum(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `apply`:

```
df['Sum']=df.apply(lambda x: x[x<0].sum(),axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution, modified from my answer in the quoted question:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [-1,2,3], 'b': [-2,3,4], 'c':[-3,4,5]})

column_names = list(df.columns)
df['neg_sum']= df[df[column_names]<0].sum(axis=1)
```

This answer allows for selecting the exact columns by name instead of taking all columns.