# pandas average across dynamic number of columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mean, series

I have a dataframe like as shown below

```
customer_id   revenue_m7   revenue_m8   revenue_m9  revenue_m10  
   1             1234         1231        1256         1239      
   2             5678         3425        3255         2345
```

I would like to do the below

a) get average of revenue for each customer based on latest two columns (revenue_m9 and revenue_m10)

b) get average of revenue for each customer based on latest four columns (revenue_m7, revenue_m8, revenue_m9 and revenue_m10)

So, I tried the below

```
df['revenue_mean_2m'] = (df['revenue_m10']+df['revenue_m9'])/2
df['revenue_mean_4m'] = (df['revenue_m10']+df['revenue_m9']+df['revenue_m8']+df['revenue_m7'])/4
df['revenue_mean_4m'] = df.mean(axis=1) # i also tried this but how to do for only two columns (and not all columns)
```

But if I wish to compute average for past 12 months, then it may not be elegant to write this way. Is there any other better or efficient way to write this? I can just key in number of columns to look back and it can compute the average based on keyed in input

I expect my output to be like as below

```
customer_id   revenue_m7   revenue_m8   revenue_m9  revenue_m10   revenue_mean_2m   revenue_mean_4m 
           1             1234         1231        1256         1239    1867              1240  
           2             5678         3425        3255         2345    2800           3675.75
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `filter` and slicing:

```
# keep only the "revenue_" columns
df2 = df.filter(like='revenue_')
# or
# df2 = df.filter(regex=r'revenue_m\d+')

# get last 2/4 columns and aggregate as mean
df['revenue_mean_2m'] = df2.iloc[:, -2:].mean(axis=1)
df['revenue_mean_4m'] = df2.iloc[:, -4:].mean(axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   customer_id  revenue_m7  revenue_m8  revenue_m9  revenue_m10  \
0            1        1234        1231        1256         1239   
1            2        5678        3425        3255         2345   

   revenue_mean_2m  revenue_mean_4m  
0           1247.5          1240.00  
1           2800.0          3675.75
```

#### if column order it not guaranteed

Sort them with natural sorting

```
# shuffle the DataFrame columns for demo
df = df.sample(frac=1, axis=1)

# filter and reorder the needed columns
from natsort import natsort_key
df2 = df.filter(regex=r'revenue_m\d+').sort_index(key=natsort_key, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

you could try something like this in reference to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42063716/pandas-sum-up-multiple-columns-into-one-column-without-last-column):

```
n_months = 4  # you could also do this in a loop for all months range(1, 12)

df[f'revenue_mean_{n_months}m'] = df.iloc[:, -n_months:-1].mean(axis=1)
```