# Pandas DF: Sum rows of numbers cast as strings into a new column

Tags: python, pandas

Ok, I'm stumped and have surfed all available pages, followed it all, and still ugh! 
So here is my df. I want to add all the values in row 4 together and have a row total at end, then do it for 5, 6, 7...  I use `.concat()` and `.sum()` and get key errors or too many arguments, tried `.groupby`, and even `.add()` (worth a try) as the columns are 'lists', nothing gives totals.

```
     1day     2day     3day     4day     5day     6day     7day
4   2.979    2.979    2.979    2.979    2.979    2.979    2.979
5   9.543    9.543    9.543    9.543    9.543    9.543    9.543
6   5.222    5.222    5.222    5.222    5.222    5.222    5.222
7   0.319    0.319    0.319    0.319    0.319    0.319    0.319
10 -4.491   -4.491   -4.491   -4.491   -4.491   -4.491   -4.491
14  2.178    2.178    2.178    2.178    2.178    2.178    2.178
15  7.507    7.507    7.507    7.507    7.507    7.507    7.507
16  0.612    0.612    0.612    0.612    0.612    0.612    0.612
17  4.488    4.488    4.488    4.488    4.488    4.488    4.488
```

I had some luck with `df.groupby(df.index)[['1day','2day'...'7day'].sum()` but it just pushes them together, not adds them. (I am aware that all the values are equal)
In excel, sum(a1:g1) but in pandas, I'm just writing into a deeper hole, please help! 
[screen shot of df, may be a better view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOk2q.png)

Comment: `df.sum(axis=1)`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas: sum DataFrame rows for given columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25748683/pandas-sum-dataframe-rows-for-given-columns)

Comment: df['sum'] = df['1day','2day','3day','4day','5day','6day','7day'].sum(axis=1) returns KeyError on ['1day', '2day' ...]

Comment: You're indexing wrong.  Literally just do `df.sum(axis=1)` . Or add an additional bracket, so `df[['1day', '2day', '3day', '4day', '5day', '6day', '7day']].sum(axis=1)`

Comment: just presses string together. 9.34  9.34  9.34 become 9.349.349.34

Comment: What is your dtypes for the columns? - can you post the results of `df.dtypes`.  What @user3483203 should work.

Comment: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

Comment: you should try resetting the index and then try the given solutions
also if the dataframe has string values u can change them into integers by df.astype
attached links to documentations

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### `.sum()` applied to DF of strings

Without Altering the original Q&A... Here is an updated answer for your revised question:

The issue is that you'll need to convert the strings to integers.  That just makes it a two step process.  I'll show all the steps so it's clear:

```
In [83]: str_lst =[[ '7',  '3',  '2', '-1',  '5',  '8',  '0'],
                [ '6',  '8',  '4',  '0',  '8',  '7',  '6'],
                [ '6',  '1',  '2',  '8',  '6', '-1',  '2'],
                [ '0', '-1',  '3',  '5',  '1',  '3',  '7'],
                [ '6',  '5',  '2',  '8',  '4',  '2',  '3'],
                [ '4', '-1', '-1',  '3',  '2',  '3', '-1'],
                [ '8',  '6',  '6',  '0',  '8',  '0',  '0'],
                ['-1',  '3',  '3',  '0',  '4',  '2',  '4'],
                [ '2',  '1',  '2',  '7',  '0',  '8',  '5'],
                [ '3',  '8',  '1',  '0',  '8',  '1',  '8']]

In [85]: df = pd.DataFrame(str_lst, columns=['1day', '2day', 
                  '3day', '4day', '5day', '6day', '7day'])

In [93]: df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric)

In [94]: df['Totals'] = df.sum(axis =1)
```

If you do the total before the `pd.to_numeric` it is the summation of strings.  If you do the total after teh `pd.to_numeric` it is the summation of integers.

#### Original Response

After you've created your DF.  Try:

```
df['Totals'] = df.sum(axis=1)
```

This will add a column at the far right with a sum of the rows.

#### Example

```
In [63]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(-1,9,size=(10, 7)),
             columns=['1day', '2day', '3day', '4day', 
                      '5day', '6day', '7day'])

In [64]: df
Out[64]: 
   1day  2day  3day  4day  5day  6day  7day
0     0     0     7    -1     2     2    -1
1     0     3     3     2    -1     3     6
2     0     8     0    -1     8    -1     1
3     3     8    -1     2     6     3     8
4     5     0     1     8     8    -1     3
5     7     8     1     4     8     1     8
6     5     7     5    -1     7    -1     1
7     6     3     2     2     8     1     5
8     3     7     3     3     3    -1     1
9     2    -1     8     1     1     0     5

In [65]: df['Totals'] = df.sum(axis=1)

In [66]: df
Out[66]: 
   1day  2day  3day  4day  5day  6day  7day  Totals
0     0     0     7    -1     2     2    -1       9
1     0     3     3     2    -1     3     6      16
2     0     8     0    -1     8    -1     1      15
3     3     8    -1     2     6     3     8      29
4     5     0     1     8     8    -1     3      24
5     7     8     1     4     8     1     8      37
6     5     7     5    -1     7    -1     1      23
7     6     3     2     2     8     1     5      27
8     3     7     3     3     3    -1     1      19
9     2    -1     8     1     1     0     5      16
```

Comment: I'm downvoting this because A), this is an obvious duplicate, and B), you just copied an answer from the comments.

Comment: I was drafting the response when you were posting in the comments - so didn't see your notes.  The OP asked for "I want to add all the values in row 4 together and have a row total at end" which `df.sum()` doesn't provide without `df['Totals']` assignment.

Comment: @user3483203, If you'd like to post your answer - i'd be happy to delete this one...

Comment: Bill, you are on the money as I have exhausted everyone's posts, tried them, and have had no luck. Your example is great, but the data is in str format, and .sum(axis=1) seems to just press them together. Appreciate the help.

Comment: I didn't post as an answer because of the dupe, but with your edit, this answer is relevant, and correct.  My -1 has been changed to a +1

Comment: Winner winner! The winning move was to add the .apply(pd.to_numeric) to the end of my df.concat line, bingo. srt to int, and math happens.  Thanks all, huge time save.