# Pandas: filter result of column summation

Tags: python, pandas

Using a pandas dataframe, for example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,0,0], 'b': [1,0,0]})
```

I have used the answer from [Pandas: sum DataFrame rows for given columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25748683/pandas-sum-dataframe-rows-for-given-columns) to sum the two columns:

```
foo = df[['a', 'b']].sum(axis=1)
```

What I'm struggling with now is how to filter the rows that are assigned to `foo`. So, for example, I only want the rows that are greater than 0 to be in the result stored in `foo`. Does anyone know the best of doing this?

Comment: Do something like this : `foo = foo[foo > 0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
foo = df[['a', 'b']]

mask = foo.gt(0).all(axis=1)

out = foo[mask].sum(axis=1)
print (out)
0    2
dtype: int64
```

**Details**:

Compare by [`DataFrame.gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.gt.html) (`>`) for greater values:

```
print (foo.gt(0))
       a      b
0   True   True
1  False  False
2  False  False
```

And then test if [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) values per rows are `True`, also is possible use [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) if need test at least one `True`, it means here one greater value per row:

```
print (foo.gt(0).all(axis=1))
0     True
1    False
2    False
dtype: bool
```

But if want filter by `foo` use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and because same index in `foo` and `df` create mask by `foo` and filter original `DataFrame`:

```
foo = df[['a', 'b']].sum(axis=1)

df = df[foo.gt(0)]
print (df)
   a  b
0  1  1
```

**Detail**:

```
print (foo.gt(0))
0     True
1    False
2    False
dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 1):

**Use Basic** You can use basics of Pandas  like `conditionality` AND `dropna`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,0,0], 'b': [1,0,0]})
foo = df[['a', 'b']].sum(axis=1)
foo = pd.DataFrame(foo)  # Converting foo into DataFrame
foo = foo[foo > 0]  # Applying the conditionality search
foo.dropna(axis=0, inplace=True)  # Droping the NaN values
foo.columns = ['Result']   # Changeing the name of column
foo
```

**Output**

```
    Result
0     2.0
```

I hope it may help you.