# Pandas - Replace row value from derived calculation

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I need to make an `inplace` value replacement based upon an row index value.  The replacement value is a sliced (both row and column) dataframe computation.

**Setup**

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd                                                                                                  

In [2]: cols = [0, 1, 'A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'B0', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3']                                                        

In [3]: data = [['sum', 4531.0010, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 7], 
   ...:         ['', 4531.0010, 5, 6, 3, 0, 5, 4, 7, 0], 
   ...:         ['', 4531.0010, 1, 3, 9, 0, 2, 2, 3, 0], 
   ...:         ['sum', 5037.0022, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 5], 
   ...:         ['', 5037.0022, 2, 2, 3, 0, 1, 3, 9, 0], 
   ...:         ['', 5037.0022, 5, 4, 7, 0, 5, 6, 3, 0]]                                                                     

In [4]: df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=cols)                                                                           

In [5]: df = df.set_index(list(df.columns[[0, 1]]))                                                                          

In [6]: df                                                                                                                   
Out[6]: 
               A0  A1  A2  A3  B0  B1  B2  B3
0   1                                        
sum 4531.0010   0   0   0   2   0   0   0   7
    4531.0010   5   6   3   0   5   4   7   0
    4531.0010   1   3   9   0   2   2   3   0
sum 5037.0022   0   0   0   8   0   0   0   5
    5037.0022   2   2   3   0   1   3   9   0
    5037.0022   5   4   7   0   5   6   3   0
```

As you can see the row is multiindexed with index=1 is a number that represents a subset of the data.  Within each data subset there is a "sum" in index=0 which I would like to "distribute" up (or down) to the zero balances.

The computation is basically the "A" columns and the index 1 rows with the same value to be summed to a denominator.  Then the sum of the row for that data group is the numerator.  The ratio is then used to distribute the sum between the rows.

For the rows=4531.0010 and the columns with an A it would be computed as:

(5+6+3)/(5+6+3+1+3+9)*2 = row 1, column A3
(1+3+9)/(5+6+3+1+3+9)*2 = row 2, column A3

The resulting `df` would look like this:

```
Out[7]: 
               A0  A1  A2     A3  B0  B1  B2     B3
0   1                                              
sum 4531.0010   0   0   0  2.000   0   0   0  7.000
    4531.0010   5   6   3  1.037   5   4   7  4.870
    4531.0010   1   3   9  0.923   2   2   3  2.130
sum 5037.0022   0   0   0  8.000   0   0   0  5.000
    5037.0022   2   2   3  2.435   1   3   9  2.407
    5037.0022   5   4   7  5.565   5   6   3  2.593
```

The number of rows are not fixed - there could be one or there could be 10.

**What I've tried**

I've tried using variations of `.pivot_table()` but I can't figure out how to reverse the process using division.  As an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15570099/pandas-pivot-tables-row-subtotals).

I've also used variations of `.sum()` but trying to constrain the `df` using slices eludes me.  One of many [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25748683/pandas-sum-dataframe-rows-for-given-columns/25748826).

I think I can get this to work with a lot of python functions, but seems that it should be possible more efficiently.  Any direction is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution working, if unique first levels of `MultiIndex`:

```
cols = [0, 1, 'A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'B0', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3']

data = [['sum1', 4531.0010, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 7], 
        ['sum1', 4531.0010, 5, 6, 3, 0, 5, 4, 7, 0], 
        ['sum1', 4531.0010, 1, 3, 9, 0, 2, 2, 3, 0], 
        ['sum2', 5037.0022, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 5], 
        ['sum2', 5037.0022, 2, 2, 3, 0, 1, 3, 9, 0], 
        ['sum2', 5037.0022, 5, 4, 7, 0, 5, 6, 3, 0]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=cols)

df = df.set_index(list(df.columns[[0, 1]]))
print (df)
                A0  A1  A2  A3  B0  B1  B2  B3
0    1                                        
sum1 4531.0010   0   0   0   2   0   0   0   7
     4531.0010   5   6   3   0   5   4   7   0
     4531.0010   1   3   9   0   2   2   3   0
sum2 5037.0022   0   0   0   8   0   0   0   5
     5037.0022   2   2   3   0   1   3   9   0
     5037.0022   5   4   7   0   5   6   3   0
```

---

```
#loop by first letters of values in columns
for c in df.columns.str[0].unique():
    #filter values by first letter
    df1 = df.filter(like=c)
    #get sum per rows
    s = df1.iloc[:, :-1].sum(axis=1)
    #get last column
    last_col = df1.iloc[:, -1]
    #replace 0 in last column to previous non 0
    last_col = last_col.mask(last_col == 0).ffill()
    #divide by sum per first level with multiple by last_col
    s = s.div(s.sum(level=0), level=0).mul(last_col)
    #add to last column
    df[last_col.name] += s
print (df)
                A0  A1  A2        A3  B0  B1  B2        B3
0    1                                                    
sum1 4531.0010   0   0   0  2.000000   0   0   0  7.000000
     4531.0010   5   6   3  1.037037   5   4   7  4.869565
     4531.0010   1   3   9  0.962963   2   2   3  2.130435
sum2 5037.0022   0   0   0  8.000000   0   0   0  5.000000
     5037.0022   2   2   3  2.434783   1   3   9  2.407407
     5037.0022   5   4   7  5.565217   5   6   3  2.592593
```

Comment: Index 0 is not unique - - but, if I reset the row index and concatenate index 0 & 1 into new column that maybe could yield the same result?

Comment: @BillArmstrong - Not sure how in real data, but how is distingush groups? Are similar like in change your data sample or unique like in question?

Comment: The row indexing is actually 5 deep - so, far more complex. But I was able to simply add a new reference column based on your answer and it works. I think I can get the iterator to use the multiindex depth and apply the .unique() and get there in one less step. Thanks.