# Numpy sum on specified columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a dataframe like so:

```
              Name     A       B       C        D       E 
Date                                                              
2000-10-19    Pete     1       0       1        1       0
2000-10-20    Joan     1       1       0        0       1     
2000-10-23    Michael  0       0       1        0       1 
2000-10-24    Carl     0       1       1        1       1
2000-10-25    Levis    1       0       1        1       0
2000-10-26    Susan    0       0       0        1       1
```

And I would like to count the "1" for each row, så it look like this:

```
              Name     A       B       C        D       E      F
Date                                                              
2000-10-19    Pete     1       0       1        1       0      3
2000-10-20    Joan     1       1       0        0       1      3
2000-10-23    Michael  0       0       1        0       1      2
2000-10-24    Carl     0       1       1        1       1      4
2000-10-25    Levis    1       0       1        1       0      3
2000-10-26    Susan    0       0       0        1       1      2
```

I think it can be done easily but Numpy, but I can't quite figure out how

But I've come up with this, now I just have to specify which columns it is to be summed on

```
df['E'] = np.sum(df, axis=1)
```

Can anybody help

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25748683/pandas-sum-dataframe-rows-for-given-columns/25748826

Comment: Not quite, but I probably didn't describe the question quite right either. To simplify the question, I probably removed a little plenty of data frame, what I did not mention was that I have a lot of other columns that contain numbers, but they must not be summed in the calculator, så I have not found the solution yet

Answer (score 3):

You can sum these up with:

```
df['F'] = np.sum(df[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']], axis=1)
```

By using `df[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']]` you thus select a subset of the columns (`A`, `B`, ..., `E`). Then we use [**`np.sum(..)`** [numpy-doc]](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html) to sum up. By specifying the `axis=1` parameter, we thus sum up *per row*, and we then assign the sums of these rows to a new column `F`.

Comment: Hi, this is a very interesting question - please can you explain this code - I am very curious what is happening. Specifically at `axis = 1` & `np.sum`

Comment: To simplify the question, I probably removed a little plenty of data frame, what I did not mention was that I have a lot of other columns that contain numbers, but they must not be summed in the calculator, I tried first Willem Van Onsem solution, but there I get a sum like this in the first row  ´10110.0´  and the second ´11001.0´ and so on, how can that be

Comment: @jhjorsal: are you sure your columns are not strings?

Comment: Sorry yes, my mistake - I thing it is bedtime :-)

Answer (score 1):

Or you can also use:

```
final=df.assign(F=df.drop('Name',1).sum(1))
```

---

```
               Name  A  B  C  D  E  F
Date                                 
2000-10-19     Pete  1  0  1  1  0  3
2000-10-20     Joan  1  1  0  0  1  3
2000-10-23  Michael  0  0  1  0  1  2
2000-10-24     Carl  0  1  1  1  1  4
2000-10-25    Levis  1  0  1  1  0  3
2000-10-26    Susan  0  0  0  1  1  2
```

Answer (score 1):

We can also do:

```
df['F']=df[df.eq(1)].count(axis=1)
print(df)

               Name  A  B  C  D  E  F
Date                                 
2000-10-19     Pete  1  0  1  1  0  3
2000-10-20     Joan  1  1  0  0  1  3
2000-10-23  Michael  0  0  1  0  1  2
2000-10-24     Carl  0  1  1  1  1  4
2000-10-25    Levis  1  0  1  1  0  3
2000-10-26    Susan  0  0  0  1  1  2
```

or

```
df['F']=df.eq(1).sum(axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you prefer using a pandas DataFrame, you can use:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['John',0,1,0,0,1,0,1],
                   ['Kate',0,0,1,0,0,0,0],
                   ['Pete',1,1,1,0,1,0,1],],
                  columns=['Name', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'])

df['SUM'] = df.sum(axis=1)
```

Result:

```
   Name  A  B  C  D  E  F  G  SUM
0  John  0  1  0  0  1  0  1    3
1  Kate  0  0  1  0  0  0  0    1
2  Pete  1  1  1  0  1  0  1    5
```

When you prefer using a numpy array, you can use:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([['John',0,1,0,0,1,0,1], ['Kate',0,0,1,0,0,0,0], ['Pete',1,1,1,0,1,0,1],],
                  columns=['Name', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'])
arr = df.values
totals = arr[:, 1:].sum(axis=1).reshape(-1,1)

np.hstack((arr, totals))
```

Result:

```
array([['John', 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 3],
       ['Kate', 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       ['Pete', 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 5]], dtype=object)
```