# Combine values in two columns to one in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset, df, where I would like to combine or sum the values in 2 specific columns to one column

**Data**

```
id  name1   name2   status
aa  1       0       y
bb  2       2       n
cc  0       1       y
```

**Desired**

```
id  name    status
aa  1       y
bb  4       n
cc  1       y
```

**Doing**

```
df['name'] = df[['name1', 'name2']].agg(axis = 1)
```

I am running this script, however, I think I am missing a key syntax. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: you have not defined any function in agg('np.sum')

Comment: Do you not mean `df['name'] = df[['name1', 'name2']].sum(axis=1)`? Or perhaps in this case `df.insert(1, 'name', df.pop('name1') + df.pop('name2'))` is better

Comment: yes @HenryEcker I believe the first statement will give desired output _ update: first soln did not not give desired . Will try 2nd soln

Comment: If that is the case, do you mind if I close this as a duplicate of [Pandas: sum DataFrame rows for given columns](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25748683/15497888)?

Comment: oh I see _ I will try second soln  now

Comment: Forewarning that `insert` is one of the few inplace operations in the entire library. Don't do `df = df.insert(...)` you'll end up with `df` being `None`. Just do `df.insert` on a line by itself.

Comment: The second soln worked- I did  df.insert(1, 'name', df.pop....  so I should do:
df.update(1, 'name', df.pop....  ?

Comment: No sorry. That was a typo I've fixed it now. My mistake. `insert` is the correct one, just don't assign back by mistake.

Comment: oh no worries this works fine. Can post as dupe thank you

Answer (score 1):

Simply doing:

```
df['name'] = df['name1'] + df['name2']
df.drop(['name1','name2'],axis=1, inplace=True)
```

will work. Pandas columns can be added or multiplied together using standard operators. This also works with columns of string or any column datatype where the operator can be mapped to each row.

If you want to learn the agg functions then you could do.

```
df['name'] = df[['name1','name2']].sum(axis=1)
df.drop(['name1','name2'],axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Both will leave df as you want. There's nothing wrong with doing things in two lines. It's often easier to read and comprehend when you're re-using the code.