# Pandas Row wise division

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose i have this dataframe

```
      A   B   C
0     1   2   3
1     4   5   6
2     7   8   9
SUM   12  15  18
```

now i want to divide each element by their respective column `"SUM"`. Example (1/12),(8/15) etc, and fill it up in place of the numbers.
I can loop it, but that would be time consuming and moreover i am sure there must be some way in which `pandas` can do it without looping.

something like this is done [Pandas sum across columns and divide each cell from that value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26537878/pandas-sum-across-columns-and-divide-each-cell-from-that-value) here, but its for row totals. I want to know how to do it for column totals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you select the last row using `iloc` then you can pass this to `div`:

```
In [20]:
df.div(df.iloc[-1])

Out[20]:
            A         B         C
0    0.083333  0.133333  0.166667
1    0.333333  0.333333  0.333333
2    0.583333  0.533333  0.500000
SUM  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000
```