# Divide a column with other columns except itself in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image: Attached image]

`df_top4` as below

I have a dataframe (`df_top4`) as below and I want to divide the entire row by total, without dividing it by itself. Is there a way I could preserve my total as I need to make a bar chart of subject `vs` total?

```
df_top4=df_top4.divide(df_top4.total, axis=0)
```

Also I want to retain the total field hence this olution([Pandas sum across columns and divide each cell from that value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26537878/pandas-sum-across-columns-and-divide-each-cell-from-that-value)) didnt work

Comment: Use `cols = df.filter(like='Student').columns` and then `df[cols] = df[cols].div(df['Total'], axis=0)`

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
mask = df.columns.str.contains('Student')
df.loc[:, mask] = df.loc[:, mask].div(df['Total'], axis=0)
```

Comment: Hi Ansev, I followed he method but getting this - 

'

  ' 2789         # Do we have a (boolean) 1d indexer?
   2790         if com.is_bool_indexer(key):
-> 2791             return self._getitem_bool_array(key)
   2792 
   2793         # We are left with two options: a single key, and a collection of keys,


   2835             )
   2836         elif len(key) != len(self.index):
-> 2837             raise ValueError(
   2838                 f"Item wrong length {len(key)} instead of {len(self.index)}."
   2839             )
'

Comment: @xnorphic2652 - Answer was edited